# Ajax вставка HTML содержимого к определенному атрибуту

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

У меня есть комментарии, к ним я хочу сделать возможность отвечать. Я хочу создать форму для ответа, которая встраивается после конкретного комментария. Но получаю другое, эта форма встраивается во все комментарии. Я понимаю, что проблема в том, что получая класс кнопки и встраивая ответ с сервера на сайт, ответ будет подставляться к каждому комментарию. Как мне вставлять к конкретному комментарию? Надеюсь понятно изложил свои мысли.

js

```
$('.reply-btn').on('click', function(event) {
let author = $(this).attr('comment-author');
let id = $(this).attr('comment-id');
let formId = $('.reply-form').attr('form-id');
if (open) {
    open = false;
    $.ajax ({
        url: "reply.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {author: author, id: id},
        success: function (reply) {
            $('.reply-form').html(reply);
        }
    });
} else {
    open = true;
    $('.reply-form').empty();
}
event.preventDefault(event);
});
```

php

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST;
if ( $data ) { ?>
    <form action="sent_reply.php" method="POST">
        <p>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['author']?>, ">
            <button type="submit" class="send-reply">Ответить</button>
        </p>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Кнопка для ответа

```
echo "<div class='comment-reply'><a href='' class='reply-btn' comment- 
id='".$comment->id."' comment-author='".$comment->author."'>Ответить</a> 
</div>";
```

Блок для вставки формы(находится внутри комментария)

```
echo "<div class='reply-form' form-id='".$comment->id."'></div>";
```

Comment: как в разметке `'.reply-btn'` соотносится с соответствующей `'.reply-form'`?

Comment: @Igor `.reply-form` это `div` в который встраивается форма

Comment: Честно говоря не очень понятно. У Вас есть комментарии, там есть кнопка "ответить" и по нажатию этой кнопке у вас аяксом тянется форма для ответа. Почему вам на фронте сразу не отрисовать всем эти формы, делая их скрытыми и по кнопке просто показывать - скрывать ?

Comment: Ну или что более верно не отрисовывать конечно формы всем, а передавать комментам id при отрисовке, он у вас есть и по нажатию сделать что то типа модального окна с формой , куда вы передаете id, а бекенд уже сам там разбирается что с этим коментом делать. В общем есть ли смысл вообще делать дополнительный аякс запрос для того чтоб просто вставить дополнительную форму в DOM ?

Comment: @zalex Да я тоже об этом подумал, сейчас попробую, спасибо!

Comment: @Malyuga это ответ не на мой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Написал без взаимодействия с бэком. Думаю для понимания принципа достаточно. Смысл - получить из event - объект, на котором он был вызван. И дальше ответ от бэка отрисовывать относительно него.

```js
showPosts();

function addComment() {
  console.log('click');
}

function showPosts() {
  fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(posts => {
    for (let idx=0; idx < 5; idx++) {
      viewPost(posts[idx], document.body);
    }
    $('.reply-btn').on('click', addComment);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw err;
  });
}
function viewPost(post, element) {
  const postCard = document.createElement('div');
  postCard.classList.add('card', 'm-2');
  postCard.innerHTML = `
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-title">
        ${post.title}
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        ${post.body}
      </div>
      <button class="reply-btn btn btn-primary">
        Add comment
      </button>
    </div>
  `;
  element.appendChild(postCard);
}

function addComment(event) {
  const postCardBody = $(event.target).parent();
  postCardBody.append(`
    <form>
      <textarea class="form-control m-2">
      </textarea>
      <button class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
    </form>
  `);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card">

</div>
```